# Forms in Django. Drop-down list

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In a django (python) project, I have a foreign key model that reflects a form to fill out. Is it possible to make it so that if the user does not find his option in the drop-down list, he has the opportunity to fill in this field, but with his own option (respectively, with saving to the database). And in the future this option will be shown in the drop-down list. Like in the picture.

[image: supporting image]

So that the user can create a new item if it is not in the dropdown list.

What should be applied to implement this idea? What can be found in the documentation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Samuel Cormier-Iijima's snippet](https://sciyoshi.com/2008/07/django-choicefield-other-choice/) provides a choice field with an option for the user to specify a choice not yet on the list.  You would populate it using the queryset of the foreign key field, and save the new choice to that model when it posts.

Comment: Thank you!!! It is cool. I didn't know about this!